# Two different apps with the same main activity's package name in android

Tags: android

Will there be problems if we publish two different Android apps but with the same fully qualified class name of the main activity? Can 3rd party apps (ads SDK for example) handle the linking to my app correctly?

Comment: Your app in playstore is identified with the package name you give. You can't publish two apps with the same package name. So there will be no problem in identification of your app if it is once published in playstore

Comment: Can you launch an activity from another app in android without knowing the application's package name that owns that activity?

Comment: you don't need to know the package name to launch an apps activity. `Intent` and `IntentFilter` will help in doing that. Refer https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html